# Where should UAirship.land() be called

Tags: android, urbanairship.com

According to the UrbanAirship docs, `UAirship.takeOff(...)` is best called in the `Application.onCreate()` method. 
What is the most suitable place to call `UAirship.land()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `UAirship.land()` whenever you no longer want your user to receive push notifications. The most common place would be wherever you have your user logout logic.